# Learning topology through problem solving

Tags: general-topology, book-recommendation

I like books like Allan Clark's Elements of Abstract Algebra in which you get exercises throughout the entire book rather than just the end of each chapter.

Also, although I have not read it yet, Halmos' Linear Algebra Problem Book sounds like a book for a person like me. Again, you learn by solving problems throughout rather than reading a lot first and then practice working with what you have just read about.

Are there any books like this on point set topology and homotopy?

Comment: Have you looked at [Elementary Topology](http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Topology-O-Ya-Viro/dp/0821845063) by Viro et al?

Comment: Some useful references can be found here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104996/big-list-of-guided-discovery-books

Comment: I liked John M Lee - introduction to topological manifolds